# Is this an invalid URI or is it just dotnet?

Tags: asp.net, uri

This is the error message I get...

> "A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (A="t&#")." Unexpected Error

from this url

http://localhost:32208/SomePage.aspx?A=t%26%23

My question is, given that %26%23 is the uri encoded version of &# why does it have a problem with it?

NB The problem occurred because of incorrect encoding, which we've fixed, but I don't know why this would be a problem anyway

Comment: How do you fix the problem ?

Comment: It was htmlencoding, then url encoding. You shouldn't need to do both